# Troubleshooting JS conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've been troubleshooting a form that allows for users to select an amount or select other amount. The other amount when clicked changes the amount to $5. I'm trying to get get it so that if say the user tries to enter a number such as 10, 15 or 20 as examples it will allow them to type it.  Currently it is converting anything less than 5 for the starting number to 5 which makes it impossible.

```
$("#donrAmountInput").on("input", function() {
  setDonrAmount("Other");
}); 

function setDonrAmount(id) {
  var amt;
  $('#donrAmountButtons .active').removeClass('active');

  if (id == "Other") {
    amt = $("#donrAmountInput").val() > 5 ? $("#donrAmountInput").val() : 5;
    $('#otherAmount button').addClass('active');
  }
  else {
    amt = id.substring(10);
    $('#donrAmount' + amt).addClass('active');
  }

  $('input#donrAmountInput').val(amt);
  $('input#donrAmountInput').change();
  $('#donrReviewAmount').html(amt);
}
```

For reference here's the actual form. Help would be greatly appreciated. https://secure.pva.org/site/c.ajIRK9NJLcJ2E/b.9381225/k.8668/FY2016_March_Congressional/apps/ka/sd/donorcustom.asp

Comment: So your problem is in this line `amt = $("#donrAmountInput").val() > 5 ? $("#donrAmountInput").val() : 5;` which says if the value is greater than 5 use it, otherwise set it to 5.

Comment: that's correct. I know that I'm setting it to 5 for anything less than 5 but can't figure out why it wont let me type 20 in.

Comment: Because when you type the "2" in "20" it sees that as less than "5". You check whenever any change is being made to the input.

Comment: I understand that. I'm hitting a mental wall on how to only trigger that after 2 chars

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `input` **type** to `number` specify `min`,`max`,`required` attributes and then check the validity of it via javascript/jQuery.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var inpObj = $("#id1")[0];
    if (inpObj.checkValidity() === false) {
        $("#demo").html(inpObj.validationMessage);
    } else {
       $("#demo").html(inpObj.value); 
}
}
$('button').on('click',function(){
myFunction();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" type="number" min="5" max="300" required>
<button>OK</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```